# Ruby rails - how to find_by multiple options?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to find records based on more than one parameters. And those parameters are of mupltiple options.

```
As "SELECT something FROM mytable WHERE user_name="xyz" and status=("Active" OR "Deleted")
```

How do I translate this to rails statement?

```
Person.find_by_user_name_and_status(user_name, status) # this doesn't take the OR operator
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but did you try this?

```
Person.find_all_by_user_name_and_status(user_name, ["active", "deleted"])
```

if the above does not work, this should...

```
Person.where(:user_name => "xyz", :status => ["active", "deleted"])
# translates to:
# "select * from persons where username = 'xyz' and status in ('active', 'deleted')"
```

You should take a look into the Rails Guide for Active Record: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks! that worked, I just made it find _all_by instead of find_all. the OR operator worded.  `Person.find_all_by_user_name_and_status(user_name, ["active", "deleted"])`

Comment: The second example does not work: Person.where(:user_name => "xyz").where(:status => ["active", "deleted"])